# Spring Boot CRUD Application with Thymeleaf - BindingResult result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app with this bean:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class UserPayload implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    @NotEmpty
    private String confirmPassword;
    @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String name;
...
}
```

and the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/adduser.html")
    public String addUser(@Valid UserPayload userPayload,
                            BindingResult result,
                            Model model,
                            @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
...
}
```

on the template:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/adduser.html}" th:object="${user}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


     <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"  placeholder="Introduce you name">

...

</form>
```

but BindingResult result shows 0 errors when all the fields are empty

Comment: Perhaps try @NotNull?

Comment: Does your `post` work? Is `addUser(...)` really called?

Comment: It is called, but when I debug BindingError has 0 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be motivated for different reasons.

One thing you can try is to annotate the `UserPayload` object with a [`ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) annotation:

```java
@PostMapping("/adduser.html")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userPayload") @Valid UserPayload userPayload,
                      BindingResult result,
                      Model model,
                      @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) {
...
}
```

Perhaps it could be of help as it seems you are also providing the `files` parameter. Please, adjust the model attribute name as appropriate.

Please, also verify that you have an implementation of the Validation API in your maven dependencies, not only the `java.validation` API, like `hibernate-validator`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Please, set the right version according with the rest of libraries in your project: if you are using Spring dependency management you can safely rely on it.